# How can I remove a file that looks like a flag?

Tags: command-line, files

While using grep with `-oG` flag I accidentally create a file named `-v`.

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username  334 Feb 10 14:29 -v`

Now I cannot figure out how to get rid of it.

I've tried:

```
rm -v
rm "-v"
rm '-v'
rm -f "-v"
rm \-v
```

This is on a server so I only have the command line. 
How do I remove this file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "--" argument to `mv` surely works (it means: "stop to interpreting strings starting with `-` as options from now on"), but it is worth to know also

```
rm ./-v
```

which will work also with commands that do not have the "--" flag.

EDIT: well-behaved commands should respect the `--` flag. But you never know.

Comment: All GNU programs should adhere to `--`. It may be defined in POSIX as well. Yup, its [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html).

Comment: Exactly. ./ will ALWAYS work.  -- will PROBABLY work.

Comment: Didn't even think of `./` and the `--` flag is good to know.

Answer (score 13):

```
rm -- -v
```

`--` signifies end of options.